# Write a mysql query to count unique(duplicates)

Tags: mysql

student table name

```
+------------+--------------+-------------------------------+-----------+
|   randomno | student_name | created_on                    | hash_value|
+------------+--------------+-------------------------------+-----------+
|          1 | Michael      |   Decemeber 19,2019,01:27 AM  | CS110     |
|          4 | Doug         |   Decemeber 19,2019,10:17 PM  | CS107     |
|          8 | Pete         |   Decemeber 19,2019,10:37 AM  | CS220     |
|          2 | Michael      |   Decemeber 18,2019,09:30 AM  | CS110     |
|         13 | Arnold       |   Decemeber 19,2019,10:37 AM  | CS110     |
|         14 | Michael      |   Decemeber 19,2019,10:57 AM  | CS910     |
|         15 | Michael      |   Decemeber 19,2019,08:30 AM  | CS910     |
|          9 | Ralph        |   Decemeber 18,2019,07:31 AM  | CS110     |
|          3 | Michael      |   Decemeber 17,2019,06:32 AM  | CS110     |
|          5 | Doug         |   Decemeber 17,2019,05:33 AM  | CS107     |
|         10 | Ralph        |   Decemeber 17,2019,04:39 AM  | CS210     |
|          6 | Samantha     |   Decemeber 16,2019,06:07 AM  | CS110     |
|          7 | Samantha     |   Decemeber 16,2019,09:17 AM  | CS110     |
|         11 | Ralph        |   Decemeber 16,2019,05:27 AM  | CS210     |
|         12 | Ralph        |   Decemeber 15,2019,04:37 AM  | CS220     |
```

hash_value of the each student is same Michael have CS110,

1. I want to group by date on the basis of student profile > if student hash_value count is more than `one` (duplicates) that student only will have to consider
2. Basically Each day i need to get the number which is duplicates on the student_name level. ex: Michael have 3 hash_value on December 19, will have to consider as 1 and mapped to December 17 since Ralph already been there at Decemeber 17

pseudo query

```
select date(created_on) as dt, count(hash_value) from sudents
where hash_value is not null group by 1 having count(hash_value) > 1) order by dt desc
```

I am doing `date(created_on)` because that will do the job

Output columns > `date and count(uniques duplicates)`

Desired result

```
December 15,2019  1(Ralph)
December 16,2019  1(Samantha)
December 17,2019  1(Micheael),1(Dough)
December 18,2019  1(Ralph)
```

out

```
December 15,2019  1
December 16,2019  1
December 17,2019  2
December 18,2019  1
```

`My Idea, Find the hash_value having count greater than 1(count(hash_value) > 1) then (aggregate to)group by first occurrence of the date`

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you show the desired result?

Comment: If you want to count by student, then you need `GROUP BY dt, student_name`

Comment: added the result @Barmar

Comment: Why isn't Ralph counted on December 17?

Comment: Why isn't there anything in the ouptut for December 19?

Comment: Why isn't Michael counted on December 18?

Comment: @Barmar that is why, Michael which appeared on December 19 and 18 already mapped to December 17

Comment: So you only count a person the first day they appear? There's nothing about that in the question. Did you ask a similar question yesterday that I didn't understand?

Comment: exactly count only first day appear if they are duplicates :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with a subquery that gets the first date for each student.

Then wrap this in a query that counts rows grouped by date.

```
SELECT DATE(created_on) AS date, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM (
    SELECT MIN(created_on) AS created_on
    FROM students
    GROUP BY student_name
) AS x
GROUP BY date
```

I don't see how the `hash_value` is relevant.